# How to define multiple project keys for quality gate in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline in which one stage is sonarqube analysis.I have a project and multiple subprojects in sonarqube.for ex `projectkey=xyz.com` `subprojectkey=abc.xyz.com`. My requirement is if quality gates didn't pass my build should fails . How i can define multiple project keys. I wrote a shell script to do the task but in that also I'm able to define only one project key.

```
PROJECTKEY="%teamcity.project.id%"
QGSTATUS=`curl -s -u  SONAR_TOKEN: http://SONAR_URL:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$PROJECTKEY | jq '.projectStatus.status' | tr -d '"'`
if [ "$QGSTATUS" = "OK" ]
then
   exit 0
elif [ "$QGSTATUS" = "ERROR" ]
then
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Scan each subproject separately, using its own projectKey?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SonarQube combines analysis report of various applications under a single report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123613/sonarqube-combines-analysis-report-of-various-applications-under-a-single-report)